# Shell script to call python program with changing arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I have images in a sub-folder. Let's the folder `images`

I have a python program which will take image arguments from the folder one by one, the images are named in sequential order (1.jpg , 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on).

The call to the program is : `python prog.py 1.jpg`

What will be a shell script to automate this ?

Please ask for any additional information.

Comment: first get all file names from folder. Run `for` loop for running python script for all files.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani sir I have no experience in writing shell scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this from the folder that contains images/:

`for i in images/*.jpg; do
  python prog.py $i
done`

Comment: Rather than surround blocks of code with backticks, it is easier to select the code and click the `{}` button in the Formatting Toolbar near **Bold** and *Italic*. Or you can put 4 spaces at the start of each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd IMG_DIR
for item in [0-9]*.jpg
do
 python prog.py $item
 echo "Item processed : $item"
done
```

You can also pass image dir as a shellscript argument

Comment: Since we are talking about POSIX shell here, `$item` needs to get quoted when passed to python, otherwise it would break if the image name has embedded spaces.

Comment: Also, since the OP is only interested in jpg file names starting with a digit, the loop should read `for item in [0-9]*.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You could do them all in parallel very simply with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel python prog.py ::: images/*.jpg
```

Or, if your Python writes to the current directory:

```
cd images
parallel python prog.py ::: *.jpg
```